# maven failsafe plugin is not reporting cucumber test execution statistics

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am using below library versions in my SpringBoot project and cucumber for integrations tests,

```
Java - 11.0.11
Maven - 3.8.1
SpringBoot - 2.3.12.RELEASE
Cucumber - 6.10.4
Junit5 Jupiter - 5.4.0
Failsafe plugin - 3.0.0-M5
```

Although cucumber feature tests are being picked up and executed, I am not seeing any execution report from fail-safe plugin,

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:integration-test (default) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /Users/ZZZ/my-project/target/failsafe-reports
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.3.12.RELEASE)

2021-07-08 INFO 77791 --- [           main] Started SpringContext in 4.018 seconds (JVM running for 6.525)

Scenario: some scenario                 # /some_scenario.feature:2
  Given some precondition
  When some action is taken
  Then something should have happened
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I am wondering what's missing in my setup which is leading to fail-safe plugin output like this,

**Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0**

More worrying thing is that even if any cucumber test fails, fail-safe is not reporting anything and maven build succeeds. This could easily lead to false positives.

Comment: It's a surefire bug. Don't use the milestone version. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/2331

Comment: thank you @M.P.Korstanje , spot on, works fine with version 2.22.2

Answer (score 1):

fixed by reverting both surefire and failsafe plugin to 2.22.2